# Solution for syncing directory hierarchy of images from Mac to iOS?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, dropbox, google-sync

I'm a photographer and need to keep an updated set of portfolio images synced from my Mac to my iOS devices and available for **offline** viewing. I have around 300 images totalling ~150MB)

Right now the directory that I want to sync looks like this on my Mac:

```
Portfolio-2015/
 Project 01/
   Car.jpg
   Boat.jpg
   Bus
 Project 02/
   Zebra.jpg
   Lion.jpg
 ..x 150
```

I've found several solutions that accommodate the syncing part of this problem but for some reason none of them them allow you to mark a folder (and its hierarchy) to work off-line on the iOS device.

So far I've tried Google Drive, Dropbox and OwnCloud. All of these have iOS clients that allow you to 'favorite' individual files for off-line access but none of them allow you 'favorite' a folder.

Does anyone know of a solution that will work for me?

Comment: Have you tried [Box](https://www.box.com/)? I think they offer this feature. (I'm not sure, as I'm currently using a combination of Dropbox and iCloud Drive)

Comment: I've just finished testing Box and it does exactly what I need. Thanks so much Lukas

Comment: I added a "real" answer. Please tap the accept button, so that other people with this question can see that the solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Box](http://box.com).

To my knowledge, they used to offer this feature.